# Query with filter using variable is not using index

Tags: sql-server

The filter on indexed field using comparison with variable in query below is not using index:

[image: not using index]

Below is query using comparison with constant, which is using index:
[image]

The related index:

[image]

Please explain why first query is not using index, and how to make it using index?

Thanks!

Comment: dtmDelivery is datetime column? please post the SQL for creation of the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a `ad-hoc` query. The engine just ignores your variable and builds an execution plan which can be used with every query no matter the value of your variable. For example, let's generate some data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[DataSource];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1000, 1) PRIMARY KEY
   ,[DateTimeCreated] DATETIME2
   ,[SampleText] NVARCHAR(4000)
);

CREATE INDEX IX_DateTimeCreated ON [dbo].[DataSource] ([DateTimeCreated]);


INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([DateTimeCreated], [SampleText])
SELECT SYSDATETIME()
      ,LEFT(REPLICATE([number], 3500), 3500)
FROM [master]..[spt_values]; 

UPDATE [dbo].[DataSource]
SET [DateTimeCreated] = '2018-01-01'
WHERE [ID] < 1051;

GO
```

and set 50 records to have date `2018-01-01`. Now, clear the buffers and the cache (do not execute on production SQL instance) and run the following queries separately:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;

GO

DECLARE @filter DATETIME2 = '2018-01-01'

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DataSource] 
WHERE [DateTimeCreated] = @filter;

GO

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DataSource] 
WHERE [DateTimeCreated] = '2018-01-01';
```

You will can see the engine builds separate execution plans for each query and you can the same executions plans as in your example (the variable value is ignored):

```
SELECT cacheobjtype, objtype, text,usecounts
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)   
WHERE [objtype] = 'Adhoc'
    AND [text] LIKE '%2018-01-01%'  
    AND [text] NOT LIKE '%dm_exec_cached_plans%'
ORDER BY usecounts DESC;
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to force the engine to build the plan respecting the value of your variable, you can use `recompile` option or `WITH INDEX` hint:

```
DECLARE @filter DATETIME2 = '2018-01-01'

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DataSource] 
WHERE [DateTimeCreated] = @filter
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

GO

DECLARE @filter DATETIME2 = '2018-01-01'

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[DataSource] WITH (INDEX = IX_DateTimeCreated)
WHERE [DateTimeCreated] = @filter;

GO
```

[image]

I have some cases, where I need to provide index hints but usually its better to have the correct indexes, to have the regular indexes maintenance and to write T-SQL statements that are easy for the engine to understand and optimize and not to worry about how he is doing his work.

In your case, the statement is pretty simple, so I believe this is just some default behavior for ignoring to value in order to speed up the ad-hoc queries. You can wrap the statement in stored procedure and to see the cache plan and the execution plan again.